# Django: is it good to have a model with more then 60 fields? And best way to develop project

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my first project in Django and I'd really like to have some advice from people with more experience then me since right now I'm a little stuck on what road take to keep developing my project.
This is my plan to develop my project:

1. Create a modelsFileFields so that my user can upload one or more standarded excel file
2. Read it and create variables with pandas
3. Create an html page with the graph with chart.js and render it in pdf with ReportLab
4. Store the pdf in my user profile usinig primary key so that they can see it and download it again.

My main problem right now is to store or not the information that are in the excel file in my database. Since getting the information in the excel file is what is important to me, my first thought was to import them and the only thing that it keeping me from doing so is the quantity of column that I have. This how my excel file looks like:

```
           total         partial      [...]
user1        10               4
user2        18               6
```

I have more then 60 variable in my excel file (so I'd need a model with more then 60 fields) and they should be doubled since I'd need the information from user1 and also user2.
So I'd like to ask if I should give up on import the csv to my database since how much big it would be and also if what I'm plannning to do has sense or if there is a better way to do so (every exemple project is welcomed).
Thanks for the helps!

Comment: There's nothing inherently _wrong_ or _good_ about a model with 60 fields. It seems high, but if you have 60 fields you have 60 fields. Without knowing what those fields are or what your data is, it's hard to say if there's a better way to organize your models. You should also ask yourself (and describe in your question) how you're going to use those fields in your app. As for size -- how many rows do you expect to have? A thousand? A hundred thousand? A million? A hundred million?

Comment: Its really a DB question, about the merits and otherwise of "wide flat tables". I think it's unquestionably good if most of the fields are never null or blank. Less so if most of them are for most instances, and there's complex conditional logic in the data processing to decide which ones need to be filled depending on (say) type and subtype fields. But there are also complications involved in the alternative, of having nullable ForeignKey or OneToOne links to related data tables